# Fast binomial sampling

Tags: binomial-distribution, sampling

This question might appear stupid, but I haven't found how to do it:

I want to simulate a sampling on a large number of samples (very large n, in the distribution $b(n, p)$, and count the results.

The only way I know is to repeat the experiment n times, each time selecting the outcome 1 with probability p, and 0 with probability (1-p), and sum the results at the end.

However, when n is very large, this becomes impractical. Is there an other, faster way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you take a very large random number sequence from 0-1  from the OEIS, and say that the experiment reached outcome 1 whenever the given number is above p

Comment: How large is $n$, and what's a typical value of $p$? When $\min \{ np,n(1-p) \}$ is large enough, the normal approximation is quite good, and the complexity of sampling from it is essentially independent of $n$. Also, how many samples from the binomial distribution itself are you taking? If the number of samples taken is considerably larger than $n$ and accuracy matters, then assembling the CDF and using a discrete sampling method might be a viable option.

Comment: n could vary from 1 to something around 10^10. I could however keep the naive method on very low values of n and switch to the normal approximation on large values, I suppose ?

Comment: If you really need to cover a range that large, then yes, you will want to do different things depending on the inputs. (Note that it depends also on $p$, not just $n$; the normal approximation of $b(1000,0.001)$ is quite inaccurate for example. That case should be handled by a Poisson approximation.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! If you move your comment(s) to an answer, I will mark it as accepted answer, as it solved my problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sampling from the binomial distribution over a wide range of values of $n$ and $p$ can't really be done in the same way in all cases. Instead we should use the normal or Poisson approximations to handle large $n$, and the exact distribution to handle small $n$.

Assuming $p \leq 1/2$, one can use a normal approximation for $np \gg 1$ and a Poisson approximation for $n \gg 1$ such that $np \sim 1$. (In practice, "$np \gg 1$" means essentially "$np>20$".) For $p>1/2$ one can draw a sample with $p$ replaced by $1-p$ using one of the above methods, and then subtract the result from $n$.

Note that although it might seem that a Poisson is at least as hard to sample as a binomial, you can write the CDF in terms of the incomplete Gamma function to make it cheap to evaluate.